# Capture text before my command and write it to an external file

Tags: luatex, write

I have some LaTeX that's something like this:

```
Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. 
Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere 
velit aliquet. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur 
ac, vestibulum at eros.\mycustomnote{Footnote text goes here}
```

What I'd like to do is capture 50 characters prior to the `\mycustomnote` call and write that our to an external file.
I've got the external file generation working great, I can't figure out how to capture text that's right before a give macro. I'm using LuaLateX in Texifier, so maybe there's a way to do it with Lua?

Comment: 50 characters of input or output? if it's  `aaaa \foo \mycustomnote{Footnote text goes here}`  and `\foo{is a thousand characters of stuff.....}`  do you want to grab `aaa \foo` or the last 50 characters of `stuff...` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If I understand your question, I'd be wanting the stuff..., basically, I want any thing that will ultimately be displayed on the page, just prior to the `\mycustomnote`.

Comment: that's kind of tricky as luatex never has that to hand, but you could use the pre-linebreak callback and re-constitute the text from the node list, although ligatures etc make that trickier than it would be otherwise.

Comment: Quite difficult. Another way is to get `\inputlineno`, open the current file (`currfile`) package in Lua, and read the file content at that line (and a bit before).

Comment: If you are e.g. in a paragraph which didn't have 50 characters yet, do you want a shorter segment or do you want to also get the end of the previous paragraph?

Comment: Getting some of the previous paragraph is no problem. I played with `\inputlineno`, but I keep getting "can't use in vertical mode" never seen that error before!

Comment: there are lots of commands you can not use in outer vertical mode, but as you have shown no code hard to say what your error is. Also I do not see how using inputlineno helps much given your reply to my first comment, that would allow you to grab some lines of the input source,  which may include unexpanded commands such as `\section` or locally defined abbreviations etc.

Comment: That makes sense, I just did some research on vertical mode, so I understand that better now. A little context might be helpful here, I've got a bunch of reference commands that are generated by an api and  exported as a .sty file that is used in my latex books. Give that they are book references, they always end up inside a custom `\note` call. I'm wanting a way to grab the text that comes just before the given note, and make that available to the api. Ideally, it'd be clean, plain text, but having some markup in it would be ok. I could parse it out, just not ideal.

Comment: In the book that I'm working on now, the notes are in a multicol layout, so it seems like that's probably why it's in vertical mode.